# Why is TOP with ORDER BY statement on view slower then retrieving all data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

We have a very complex view (not indexed) with a lot of calculated properties for statistic data. This view references some other indexed views also.

On this view we want to implement a GUI with pagination and sorting support and observed some very strange behavior when sorting `DESC`.

*Using `ROW_NUMBER` pagination support was very slow until (even with timeout) when the page number increased. So we searched for an alternative.*

*v.ID* is the primary key of one of the referenced tables with `ASC` sorting.

**Slow:** *35 seconds*

```
SELECT TOP(100) v.* FROM View AS v WHERE v.ID > 100 AND v.bar != 0 ORDER BY v.foo DESC;
```

**'Fast:'** *4 seconds*

```
SELECT v.* FROM View AS v WHERE v.ID > 100 AND v.bar != 0 ORDER BY v.foo DESC;
```

We use SQL Server 2008.

In this case the `TOP` statement is only fast if no sorting provided.

Does sorting has an influence on top?

Comment: See execution plan what is underneath. And compare both

Comment: yes, sorting forces the db to sort the result set BEFORE it applies top(). otherwise top would be next to useless. e.g. "get best 10 scores in NHL hockey games". if top was applied first, you'd just get the first 10 records encountered, which almost certainly would NOT be the best scores.

Comment: @MarcB: although it doesn't explain why TOP 100 is slower than to return all rows

Comment: Probably because `v.ID` is clustered index, no real sort needed, check execution plan

Comment: Why is it clustered? this view is not indexed. We sort by other property in reality with same results.

Comment: @djmj Share execution plans for both

Comment: Have you performed repeated measurements, and with the statements both ways around? If you've just run the slow query, then immediately after the fast query, it's possible that the slow query incurred significant cost to load everything into memory and now the fast query is benefiting from that cached data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes we have executed these queries in different orders. Same results.

Comment: @lad2025 Execution plan is really large and Boss is not around and so I dont know if i am allowed to share it.

Comment: With no execution plan it is mostly guess work, but I would guess that there is an underlying index on `v.foo`. With the `TOP` operator, and ordering by `v.foo` SQL Server has possibly decided that the most efficient plan is to do an index seek on this index an use nested loops, and possibly spools to to retrieve the rest of the data, without the top it is likely using a simple clustered index scan/seek with merge joins. In your case the additional expense of the slower join operations has not outweighed the benefit of the non clustered index seek on `foo`.

Comment: One possible workaround is to use a variable for the top operator - `DECLARE @top INT = 100; SELECT TOP (@top) `, Since at compilation time `@top` is not known, SQL Server must compile a "fits all" plan, which will usually use intermediate materialisation to build the full result set, then apply top, rather than trying to be clever and get the top results and build the rest of the data around it.

Answer (score -1):

That's because in sql server the TOP is calculated AFTER order by. In other rdbms like oracle (instead of top X is used rownum <= X) it's calculated before order, so you must use a subquery. Probably sql server does something similar inside, you should see it in execution plan

Edit:
I don't get why the downvotes...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.105).aspx

> If the query includes an ORDER BY clause, the first expression rows, or expression percent of rows, ordered by the ORDER BY clause are returned. If the query has no ORDER BY clause, the order of the rows is arbitrary.

In order to select the ordered top 100, first it must order and then select the top 100. Cause it's not indexed it must order the full table and then take the top